# Checking for Visual C++ Redistributable 2017 vs 2015 using minor version

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, redistributable, visual-c++-2015, visual-c++-2017

Our application checks for the installed version of the Visual C++ redistributable by looking at the Installed Registy key using (for the 2010 version):

```
Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\VC\VCRedist\x86");
```

I need to extend the check for Visual C++ redistributable 2017, and I need to be able to distinguish it from the 2015 version. However, both versions are under ...\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\..., so I need to change which keys to check for.

I presume I can look at the Minor key that gives the minor version of the installed redistributable. But I don't have an exhaustive list of which minor version falls under 2015/2017. I know minor version 0 is 2015 and 11 is 2017, but I don't know if there were more minor versions released. If there are, I'd like to know which minor version is the "cutoff" between 2015 and 2017.

Comment: It is pretty risky to depend on somebody else's implementation detail.  Looks to me that the key was renamed to "Runtimes" at VS2012.  And discontinued completely at VS2017.  Prevailing wisdom is to prefer local deployment, to leave it up to the redist installer itself to figure out if it needs to install, update or do nothing, and worry only about the version number that your program was tested with and assume that a greater version is compatible.

Comment: We're using this check to know if the customers who've installed this application have installed the new C++ redistributable that will be required for a future version of the application. We're making the redistributable available, but if they will not or cannot install it, and suddenly cannot run the only valid version of the application anymore, we have a problem too. Hence, we want our application to make this check ahead of time.